# How do I turn off the Front Row keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard

I keep accidentally hitting <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> and bringing up Front Row. How can I disable this shortcut?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under **Keyboard & Mouse** on System Preferences there is a *Keyboard Shortcuts* tab.

[image: System preferences]

Comment: Wow. that's a classic screenshot: 10.2 or 10.3 era.

Comment: @Chealion: Yes it is.

Comment: In Snow Leopard, it's no longer “Keyboard & Mouse,” just “Keyboard.” (Mouse has its own preference pane.) You can select “Front Row” from the list of applications on the left, then uncheck the “Hide and show Front Row” entry, or reassign to a different key combination.

Comment: Also, in Lion there is no Front Row, which helps remove the problem via the back door :)