# How do I disable Front Row?

Tags: front-row

My Mac mini is picking up the same remote signals as my apple TV remote.  How can I turn off Front Row so it doesn't start playing music / videos when I am browsing my Apple TV?

Comment: Front Row was removed on 10.7, so another option would be to upgrade OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way to solve your problem is to simply disable the IR remote control receiver.  Visit this preference under

System Preferences -> Security -> General

and uncheck the box labeled "Disable remote control infrared receiver".

Answer (score 0):

There are three things you can do to turn off Front Row:

1. you can disable your keyboard shortcut: [How do I turn off the Front Row keyboard shortcut?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56/how-do-i-turn-off-the-front-row-keyboard-shortcut)
2. You can turn off your IR receiver in System Settings / Security
3. You can delete / rename the Front Row app

For more detail, see:
http://www.macyourself.com/2011/05/15/how-to-disable-front-row-in-mac-os-x-along-with-its-shortcut/