# Stop iPhone from reacting to Apple remote

Tags: iphone, apple-remote-desktop

My iPhone, when docked, reacts to the Apple remote. I cannot find the setting to disable the behaviour. Any idea where the setting is?

Comment: What do you mean by "docked." Is it connected to your Mac? If so, [disable the infrared receiver](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/54660/23703)

Comment: By "docked", I mean it is sitting in the docking station.

Comment: Disabling the infrared receiver on the Mac (didn't know a Mac Pro even had such a thing) didn't stop the iPhone from reacting to the remote control.

Comment: I was merely trying to rule out a possibility. Specifying  MacPro and hunting at a universal dock  clears things up a bit.

Comment: Can you edit the question to specify the type of dock you are using, the type of computer, and what OS version?

Comment: Type of computer turns out to be inconsequential since the infrared receiver is in the dock. Why was the question downvoted?

Comment: I'm not going to edit the question. I expect others with the same problem also to assume that the phone itself reacts to the remote control and google for the issue accordingly without specifically mentioning that they are using the standard dock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your problem is actually in the [manual for your Universal Dock](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Apple_Universal_Dock.pdf). The link is for a recent model.  Pairing should be the same for many.  Consult the manual for your model if in doubt. Following the instructions in the manual.

The best approach is to pair the dock with a particular remote so that it only responds to *a single remote.* if you have a spare remote (sounds like you do) then choose one of them and pair it with your dock.

If this is not an option, then you'll need to physically block the infrared receiver on the dock to keep it from "seeing" any remotes.

Yet another option: take the dock out of the situation.  Plug your phone in directly via an iPhone cable.

Comment: Wow. Apple do make some annoying stuff. A way to remote control a mobile device, but only when it is docked. How convenient... Anyway, I don't think I can waste a remote on this dock just to avoid another remote interacting with the dock. Best way to deal with this might be to break the infrared receiver in the dock. Maybe some tape will do. Ta.

Comment: You could always just plug your phone in via a basic iPhone cable instead of the dock.

Comment: Apple did design the dock to work in your use case with some simple extra steps. It sounds like they did their job. I forget to read the manuals sometimes too.

Comment: The simple extra steps involve a second remote control. All I need is the dock responding to no remote at all. Who needs a dock connected to a computer to respond to a remote? If I need to control the phone from afar, I'd take the phone with me. The phone is only in the dock when I am sitting at the computer connected to the dock.

Comment: There are a few ways to solve the problem *if you actually want a solution*.  I understand your frustration.  I don't waste a USB port on a dock for similar reasons.  I simply plug my phone in via cable. Apple meant for the dock to perform multiple purposes--like feeding audio to a stereo for instance. You're using it in the simplest of use cases--for power / sync.

Comment: Hm... I am using the computer the dock is connected to to play music and act as a stereo.